# How can I add a single space in Yahoo Pipes, that will not be removed?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-pipes

I'm learning to create a Twitter bot using Yahoo pipes, and here's [my pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=501062fa434fa015fdb8ddbc32ee349b). The pipe is working, but I have a problem when I run it. This is a sample of the result:

> Follow kami untuk mendapatkan cerita renungan kristen RT **@InggrianiVeeTiap** langkahku di atur oleh Tuhan:)

`@InggrianiVeeTiap` is wrong, the correct username is `@InggrianiVee`, and `Tiap`  is a part of the tweet.

I tried adding a space between them, which appears to be working, but it is removed when I save my pipe in Yahoo and try to run it.

How do I keep the space?

Comment: its not about the code, its on yahoo pipes, no code used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that you have a string builder with a space. The space is working as expected while developing, but is removed (or trimmed) after you save the pipe.

To escape the space so it will not be removed, you can use `&#32;` instead of a space (32 is the decimal ASCII code for a space).

Working example: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=9ad4bc3c1a7a6f2cb7823323f3e4323a

Comment: i see, so i missed that &#32 on string builderm, how do i know that &#32 is a space ? what if i change the space &#32 with comma (,) or (!) ? 

can you show me the relevant link ?

Comment: @nencor - Generally, you do not need these codes - the bug is that Yahoo automatically removes a single space, assuming the fields is empty. What I did is to use JavaScript, and run `" ".charCodeAt(0)`. For common characters, you can also use a good old [ascii table](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Comment: assuming i want to add exclamation at the end of tweet, so i get new string on string builder, and paste '&#33;' ?

Comment: @nencor - That seems to be working. Actually, I'd assume `!` would work - but it doesn't... I can't find anything about it though. Still looking.